# Pseudo Algorithm for Tournament Brackets

Tags: algorithm, html-table, pseudocode

I've seen all of the other topics on SO for tournament brackets, but they are all language-specific and aren't well-documented on the basic structure of a tournament bracket.

I'm looking for the algorithm in a table for determining the correct cell location of subsequent rounds, given the first round.

Something along the lines of:

```
0 Team 1
1 Team 2    Team 3
2 Team 3
3                    Team 6
4 Team 4
5 Team 5    Team 6
6 Team 6
7
8 Team 7
9 Team 8    Team 9
10Team 9
11                    Team 9
12Team 10
13Team 11   Team 11
14Team 12
```

Assuming one winner per matchup, with one row of spacing between matchups. The number of teams per first round matchup can change.

I'm trying to come to an algorithm that'll give me 1, 5, 9, and 13 for the 2nd round, 3 and 11 for the 3rd round, and 7 for the 4th round.

Comment: What have you tried? What are the rules around going from 3 teams per match to 2 teams per match? If you're using HTML tables, why not just exploit `rowspan` and `vertical-align: middle`?

Comment: The row is merely the arithmetic mean of the rows feeding that match.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: The idea of rowspan came to mind, but I was interested in the actual algorithms for finding the correct cell index